# How to move Orbit nav arrows outside of container with Foundation 4?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm using Orbit to show some text heavy elements and the arrows are getting in the way of my text. I'm weary of doing any sort of fancy css33 to increase their transparency as I need this to look right in Firefox for OS9, which I think means  Firefox 3...

So is there some way I can just move the arrows outside of Orbit's containers? Even better would be if below the container I had prev arrow, then the bullets, then the next arrow?

Answer (score 4):

This CAN be done with CSS. Natively, the overflow:hidden is on the .orbit-container. If you make .orbit-container overflow:visible and then add overflow:hidden to the .orbit-slides-container, the slides will still be hidden but anything outside the UL can be moved anywhere you'd like. Here's how I did mine:

```
.orbit-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.orbit-slides-container {
    overflow: hidden !important;    
}
.orbit-container .orbit-prev {
    margin-left: -50px;
}
.orbit-container .orbit-next {
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So is there some way I can just move the arrows outside of Orbit's
>   containers? Even better would be if below the container I had prev
>   arrow, then the bullets, then the next arrow?

There is always a way and sometimes it's not that easy. And for your particular scenario it will only be easy if you are very good in javascript. As of the latest version that is `4.1.5` event handling or callbacks are still not supported. If you want support for what you need then you really need to modify `foundation.orbit.js` and do two things:

1. Modify the script file so you can write the arrows in the place where you want them to be
2. Modify the script file so you can hook in events for the *next* and *prev* actions. Then you can add your own previous and next buttons and place them where ever you want them to be.

There's just no easy way of doing it right now. I am actually trying to contribute some codes enabling support for callbacks, simply because we would need them soon. I then would submit it to Zurb (github) and see if it will make sense to them to incorporate it to the core script.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your help Von. What I ended up doing was using css to make the box and the arrow almost totally transparent and then made them way more colorful on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also use mouseenter mouseleave and put a stop before the animation

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".orbit-container").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".orbit-prev,.orbit-next").stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 400);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $(".orbit-prev,.orbit-next").stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 400);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently did something like what you're talking about (I think).  I set the container to specific column widths inside of my slides and naturally Orbit will take up 100% of the page if there isn't a container around Orbit.

I did something like this for each slide.  Theres a bunch of extra markup here but I needed to have better control over the media queries on the slides.

```
   <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
     <ul id="home-slider" data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:2500; bullets:false;">
       <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="large-10 column push-1">
             <div class="slider-content">   
               <div class="large-6 column text-center text-left">
                 <h2>Test</h2>
                 <h3>Test</h3>
                 <p>Test</p>
                 <a href="" class="large secondary button expand">LEARN MORE</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
```

> So is there some way I can just move the arrows outside of Orbit's
>   containers? Even better would be if below the container I had prev
>   arrow, then the bullets, then the next arrow?

I struggled with this too for a minute, you can find the css for the prev / next buttons on lines 3064-3076.  You could try setting the top property to 80%+ to see if that pushes the previous and next arrows down to the bottom.